# Azure domain url not showing my page routes

Tags: url, azure, routes

I got problem trying to set the URL of my site. The project is based on mvc azure.

Usually azure has URL like: `xyz.cloudapp.net` So when i set my site live i added a domain that points to the azure project. `www.xyz.com`.

The issue is that if i try to click on 'Contact' or 'About' buttons i want the URL on the browser to show up as `www.xyz.com/about` and `www.xyz.com/Contact`. But whenever i click on the about or contact button, the browser URL still shows as `www.xyz.com`.

I have over 50 pages in my site however, Google is only indexing it as one.  Can some one please tell me how can i get this URL showing the pages i am routing too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use domain control panel, can routing with cname or A record. Use Url routing "/Contact" make sure "/"

For A record, use Azure Production VIP and enter the two recording. one hostname null(xyz.com), two hostname www(www.xyz.com). May also be a name you want to(my.xyz.com).

For cname, The only difference, dont use VIP. Instead use xyz.cloudapp.net

Use domain control panel for all these processes.

[Sample Azure Url](http://eticaret.cloudapp.net/)

[Sample Cname Url](http://www.networklifecard.com/)

[DNS Check](http://www.intodns.com/networklifecard.com) see end of document WWW A Record